# How to find lim sup and lim inf

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and define $A_n$ as

$$ \begin{cases} (-1/2,1] &\text{if } n  \text{ is odd} \\ 
(-1,1/n] & \text{if } n \text{ is even} \end{cases} $$

Find the $\limsup A_n$ and $\liminf A_n.$

If $n$ is odd then I'll have $(-1,1]$ $(-1/2,1]$ etc and the way that I see it is that the term on the right will be getting closer and closer to one and my set will be getting smaller and smaller and therefore ill have an infinite number of sets.

How does this translate into finding the lim sup or lim inf?

Similarly for n is even the set $(-1,1]$ $(-1,1/2]$ is getting smaller and smaller. How can I then choose find ONE lim inf and ONE lim sup in an infinite number of sets to choose from. Unless I misread the question and i'm looking at this all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

By the concrete expression for $\limsup$ and $\liminf$, we should find $\bigcap_{k\geqslant n} A_k, \bigcup_{k\geqslant n} A_k$. Clearly,
$$
\bigcap_{k \geqslant 2n-1} A_k= \bigcap_{k \geqslant 2n} A_k = (-1/2,1] \cap \bigcap_{k\geqslant n}(-1, 1/2k] = (-1/2, 1] \cap (-1, 0] = (-1/2, 0], 
$$
then 
$$
\liminf_n A_n = \lim_n \bigcap_{k \geqslant n} A_k= (-1/2, 0];
$$
and
$$
\bigcup_{k \geqslant 2n-1} A_k= \bigcup_{k \geqslant 2n} A_k = (-1/2,1] \cup \bigcup_{k\geqslant n}(-1, 1/2k] = (-1/2, 1] \cup (-1, 1/2n] = (-1, 1],
$$
thus
$$
\limsup_n A_n = \lim_n \bigcup_{k \geqslant n} A_k = (-1, 1].
$$